# Merging two blender addons

Tags: python

I'm trying to merge two blender addons as the meshes I'm trying to import are around 300 meshes, and the meshes need a special addon to import. I want to merge a bulk import addon with the mesh import addon. If anybody got any advice or if someone would help I would be happy.